# Pre Post MultiMatrix multiplication using Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensor, numpy-ndarray

I want to calculate the Variance of a portfolio:

Assuming I have 2 assets with weights:

```
weights = np.array([.3,.7]).reshape(1,2)
```

And the following 2 correlation matrices:

```
correl = np.array([[[1,.4],[.4,1]],[[1,.6],[.6,1]]])
```

I would like to do the weight x correl[0] & weight x correl[1] in one step

Is there a way to select the axis of the (2,2,2) tensor to multiple the submatrices?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix multiplication operator `@` treats more-than-two dimensional arrays as stacks of matrices, so all you need to do is

```
>>> weights @ correl
array([[[0.58, 0.82]],

       [[0.72, 0.88]]])
>>> 
# one-matrix-at-a-time for reference
>>> weights @ correl[0]
array([[0.58, 0.82]])
>>> weights @ correl[1]
array([[0.72, 0.88]])
```